# Debug VSA Script

Tags: debugging, vbscript

I'm using an obsolete script engine: `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Vsa.VsaEngine`. This engine is implemented in an application made in 2003, where the user can write VBScript to do some tasks.
Is it possible to debug the script (stored in a db)?

While debugging the application and running the script inside the application the following is done:

On the VsaEngine the `GenerateDebugInfo = true`.

In the script the debugger is attached:

```
Dim debugger as boolean
debugger = System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()
if debugger then
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DEBUGGER LAUNCHED!")
else
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DEBUGGER NOT LAUNCHED!")
end if
```

Visual studio's shows the DEBUGGER LAUNCHED! message in the output pannel.
When forcing a break in the script by `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` the debugger kicks in with the message 'There is no source code available for the current location'.

Q: How can I debug the Visual Basic Script in the VsaEngine?

Comment: Pure Voodoo - try to put a `Stop` in the VBScript code.

Comment: Was one of the first things i tried, the problem is not to attach the debugger or stop the script from running, but to show the loaded script.

Comment: sorry for the Voodoo - and perhaps I'll have to apologize again, but did you look at http://microsoft.public.dotnet.scripting.narkive.com/AtQ4BV0q/debugging-and-vsa (as a base to argue with your boss?).

Comment: Hmm, that's not the thing I was hoping for ;-(. I think I keep the script debugging by 'Debug.WriteLine'...